# Any method to batch-compress multiple files?

Tags: windows-7, batch, compression, gzip

Does anyone know how multiple files can be GZIP compressed?
I have lots of files in a folder and I need to compress them individually.

Actually, I've found a way to do it. GZIP command line binary does the job.

I've used `gzip -r dir`.

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Win7 , sorry :)

Comment: @avetarman, Please add what you did as an answer, and accept it, rather than just putting the answer in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the gzip alone.

by default, gzip will take any file passed to it and compress it and add the .gz extension.  i.e.

```
gzip dir/* -r
```

would gzip every file in dir/* (and sub-directories).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following in powershell (after going to the correct directory):

`$files = get-childitem`
`foreach ($file in $files) {gzip $file}`

That will go through all the files in the directory, and compress all of them.

**Edit:** If you want to do all of the files in a directory tree (i.e. in a folder and all its subfolders) just change `$files = get-childitem`  to `$files = get-childitem -recurse`

Comment: This could be extended for just about any CLI-capable compression utility, including 7zip.

Comment: Yup. Nice and adaptable that way. (on an unrelated note, when you edit links, check them first as I have seen some missed parenthesis on some of your edits. Not a big deal, but I thought you should know)

Comment: Thx for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `for` loop. Are you concerned that the executable will be loaded many times? That should not be much, compared to the time taken to compress.

Comment: Perhaps provide the code that will do this?

Answer (score 2):

GZIP can be used to compress individual files sure... but most of the time you'll see minimal amounts of disk-space savings.  Files that take up 1 sector will consume 1-full-sector of disk space, even if the file is less than the sector-size.  (i.e. sector-size = 16kb, the file is 8kb... 'compressed' is 5kb... still takes up 16kb of "disk-space")  The power of gzip is much more evident when you combine all the files into a single file (using tar typically) and then compress the singular archive.  (combined, the "archive" can take all the files and combine them into 1 singular file on the disk... which will have less "dead-space" between sectors)

For example:

```
tar -czf compressed_archive.tgz folder/*
```

tar `-c` creates an archive, `z` uses gzip compression, and `f` writes the results to a file called compressed_archive.tgz.  You can also switch to using bz2 compression (which does better in many cases) by simply switching the `z` switch to a `j`.

If you want to then extract files from the archive, you can simply do the reverse

```
tar -zxf compressed_archive.tgz
```

which would `x` extract the files that were `z` gzip'd, `f` from the archive file called compressed_archive.tgz.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need an archive. I was looking for compressing the files recursively. It's for a sitemap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)** for better compression

Comment: Thanks, but it only makes a single compressed archive. It doesn't treat the files individually.

Comment: Siva that is not an answer to the question.
It is a statement of a true fact. A unrelate true fact

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to adapt soandos powershell method to get this to work as expected (I would have added comment, but not allowed to yet).

```
$files = get-childitem -recurse | % { $_.FullName }
foreach ($file in $files) {gzip $file}
```